# How do I create new rows in the dataframe using conditions (ifelse)?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, plyr

Example: Given a data frame containing

```
 df1 = data.frame(
 users=c("1", "1", "2", "2"), 
 projects=c("100", "101", "102", "103"), 
 from=c("0", "111", "0", "106"))

| users | projects | from |
|-------|----------|------|
|     1 |      100 |    0 |
|     1 |      101 |  111 |
|     2 |      102 |    0 |
|     2 |      103 |  106 |
```

I would like to create new rows in the dataframe when the "from" column is non-zero and the new line will contain the same user and the project = from value.

then I should have,

```
df2 = data.frame(
users=c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"), 
projects=c("100", "101", "111", "102", "103", "106"), 
from=c("0", "111", "111","0", "106", "106"))

| users | projects | from |
|-------|----------|------|
|     1 |      100 |    0 |
|     1 |      101 |  111 |
|     1 |      111 |  111 |
|     2 |      102 |    0 |
|     2 |      103 |  106 |
|     2 |      106 |  106 |
```

I thought about using rbind with ifelse condition, but I can not do it.

What is the recommended approach to perform this dataframe? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new data frame containing the new rows, then bind the two data frames together.

```
library('tidyverse')

extras <- df1 %>%
  filter(from != 0) %>%
  mutate(projects = from)

bind_rows(df1, extras) %>%
  arrange(users, projects)
#>   users projects from
#> 1     1      100    0
#> 2     1      101  111
#> 3     1      111  111
#> 4     2      102    0
#> 5     2      103  106
#> 6     2      106  106
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'd need to use rbind and ifelse, but that way it works.